# Does creating local alias for a variable add overhead?

Tags: c++, reference

Consider following cases

```
void func(const A& a)
{
    //Case 1:
    const int& val = a->b->c->d;
    func1(val);
    func2(val);

    //Case 2:
    func1(a->b->c->d);
    func2(a->b->c->d);

    //Case3:
    int val = a->b->c->d;
    func1(val);
    func2(val);
}
```

w.r.t readability, Case3 is most straightforward

w.r.t to speed, For a decent compiler, Are all the above cases equivalent? If not which of them are fastest and slowest?

Assume all the pointers are raw pointers and they point to objects in heap.

Update: Assume the argument is a `const` one as shown above and so func1 and func2 may take the arguments either by value or by const reference.

Comment: It's worth noting that those three code-snippets might actually be non-equivalent, if it's possible for `func1` to modify `a`, `a->b`, `a->b->c`, and/or `a->b->c->d`. So the only way that a compiler could optimize them all into identical code is if it has access to the definition of `func1`, or can somehow otherwise confirm that they're functionally equivalent.

Comment: @ruakh how does `func1` modify `a`, `b` or `c` if it's only passed the value of `d`?

Comment: @Dave: Maybe `a` is a global variable.

Comment: Even if a is made const, can compiler now optimize or still, there is a chance of a different thread modifying what a->b->c points to. So I guess, compiler would not optimize that.

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rJz0_l

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming both functions take their argument by value*, Case 3 is at least as fast as Case 1 which is at least as fast as Case 2.

As ruakh mentioned in the comments, there's some complex dataflow analysis required before optimization occurs.

If the function parameters are references, then the final memory load of the value might never take place.  Then Case 1 would be fastest.

And if those are macros rather than functions, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

in the first scenario you make a reference in val to a->b->c->d, therefor from the compiler's pov val is a dereferenced pointer.

wrt speed the third one is the fastest as it simply creates a copy of the value than uses that one.

the problem with the first two methods is that you have to dereference the pointers to get the value so you have to do

```
case 1
lea eax,[ebp+a]
push eax

case 2
lea eax, [ebp+a]
lea ebx, [eax]
....

case 3
mov eax [ebp+val]
push eax
```

and you can clearly see that the third one is the fastest

Comment: I see. But if d was of not a primitive, Will case1 or case2 be fastest?

Comment: case 1 would be faster than case 2